# EclipseLink lazy loading hangs on reference class

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, lazy-loading

I am attempting to query `a person by id` and in my schema below i have a `@OneToMany` reference between `Address` and `Person` and a `ManyToOne` reference between person and School. I use a named query and query hints to get the best performing query for this simple task but looking at the stack trace (Relevant parts posted), EclipseLink generates three Select statements when all i want is the person object by id? Using eager fetching was killing performance and so my question is how can i simply create a query using JPQL that gets me a single person object by ID without referencing other classes?

```
@NamedQuery(
        name="findPersonById",
        query="SELECT p FROM Person as p  WHERE p.id = :id",
                hints={@QueryHint(name="eclipselink.batch.type", value="JOIN"),
                @QueryHint(name="eclipselink.batch", value="p.address")
                }
)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "TABLE_GEN", table = "PERSON_SEQUENCE_TABLE", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = "PER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 10000)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TABLE_GEN")
    @Column(name = "personID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "addressID")
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "schoolID")
    private School school;

}
```

The Address Entity

```
public class Address {


    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "ADDRESS_TABLE_GEN", table = "ADDRESS_SEQUENCE_TABLE", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = "ADDR_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ADDRESS_TABLE_GEN")
    @Column(name = "addressID")
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "address")
    private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
```

Named Query implementation

```
public Person getPersonQueryBatch(Long id){

    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    Person person = null;

    try {

         List<Person> results = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findPersonById")
        .setParameter("id", id)
        .getResultList();
        if(!results.isEmpty()){
            // ignores multiple results
            person = results.get(0);
        }
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    entityManager.close();
    return person;

}
```

Stack Trace: The last bit where it searches for an `addressID` that equals 1 is hanging

```
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.78--ServerSession(1259621282)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Begin deploying Persistence Unit persistenceUnit; session file:/Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-2.8.0.RELEASE/dugsimanager/target/classes/_persistenceUnit; state Deployed; factoryCount 2
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.781--ServerSession(1259621282)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--End deploying Persistence Unit persistenceUnit; session file:/Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-2.8.0.RELEASE/dugsimanager/target/classes/_persistenceUnit; state Deployed; factoryCount 2
[EL Finer]: connection: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.787--ServerSession(1259621282)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--client acquired: 67158058
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.788--ClientSession(67158058)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 1296566131
[EL Finest]: query: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.788--UnitOfWork(1296566131)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="findPersonById" referenceClass=Person sql="SELECT personID, TYPE, DATEADDED, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, ACTIVE, BIRTHDAY, EMAILADDRESS, GENDER, IMAGEPATH, MARITAL, PRIMARYTELEPHONE, SECONDARYTELEPHONE, version, addressID, schoolID, ETHNICITY, HISPANIC, MAJOR, NATIVELANGUAGE, RELIGIOUSAFFILIATION, studentId FROM PERSON WHERE (personID = ?)")
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.789--ServerSession(1259621282)--Connection(65769329)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.789--ServerSession(1259621282)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.79--ServerSession(1259621282)--Connection(1578517945)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT personID, TYPE, DATEADDED, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, ACTIVE, BIRTHDAY, EMAILADDRESS, GENDER, IMAGEPATH, MARITAL, PRIMARYTELEPHONE, SECONDARYTELEPHONE, version, addressID, schoolID, ETHNICITY, HISPANIC, MAJOR, NATIVELANGUAGE, RELIGIOUSAFFILIATION, studentId FROM PERSON WHERE (personID = ?)
    bind => [10000]
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.798--ServerSession(1259621282)--Connection(65769329)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].
2012-06-26 20:47:29,802 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Student': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person.entityManager
2012-06-26 20:47:29,803 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
[EL Finest]: query: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.821--ServerSession(1259621282)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="address" referenceClass=Address sql="SELECT DISTINCT t0.addressID, t0.CITY, t0.COUNTRY, t0.STATE_US, t0.STREETADDRESS, t0.STREETADDRESS2, t0.version, t0.ZIPCODE FROM ADDRESS t0, PERSON t1 WHERE ((t0.addressID = t1.addressID) AND (t1.personID = ?))")
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.821--ServerSession(1259621282)--Connection(420965983)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.821--ServerSession(1259621282)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.822--ServerSession(1259621282)--Connection(1364143063)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT DISTINCT t0.addressID, t0.CITY, t0.COUNTRY, t0.STATE_US, t0.STREETADDRESS, t0.STREETADDRESS2, t0.version, t0.ZIPCODE FROM ADDRESS t0, PERSON t1 WHERE ((t0.addressID = t1.addressID) AND (t1.personID = ?))
    bind => [10000]
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.825--ServerSession(1259621282)--Connection(420965983)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].
2012-06-26 20:47:29,826 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Address': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Address.entityManager
2012-06-26 20:47:29,827 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
2012-06-26 20:47:29,830 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Student': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person.entityManager
2012-06-26 20:47:29,831 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
[EL Finest]: transaction: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.832--UnitOfWork(1296566131)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--[EL Finest]: query: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.844--ServerSession(1259621282)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="persons" referenceClass=Person )
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.845--ServerSession(1259621282)--Connection(36219749)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.845--ServerSession(1259621282)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-06-26 20:47:29.845--ServerSession(1259621282)--Connection(1007449342)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT personID, TYPE, DATEADDED, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, ACTIVE, BIRTHDAY, EMAILADDRESS, GENDER, IMAGEPATH, MARITAL, PRIMARYTELEPHONE, SECONDARYTELEPHONE, version, addressID, schoolID, ETHNICITY, HISPANIC, MAJOR, NATIVELANGUAGE, RELIGIOUSAFFILIATION, studentId FROM PERSON WHERE (addressID = ?)
    bind => [1]
```

Test case that runs the query

```
public void testSavingPersonSchool(){

        PersonService personService = new PersonService();
        System.out.println("here\n");
        Person cPerson = personService.getPersonQueryBatch(Long.valueOf("10000"));
        System.out.println("not here\n");
        School school = new School();
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setStreetAddress("eer street");
        address.setCity("hiokins");
        address.setZipCode("34343");
        address.setState_us("MN");
        address.setCountry("usa");

        school.setName("Maui");
        school.setDescription("Thinking of dropping a summer class?");
        school.setAddress(address);
        school.setPrimaryPhone("3242342342");
        school.setAdmissionsPhone("3242342342");
        school.setAdmissionsEmailAddress("ads@d.com");
        school.setActive(true);
        cPerson.setSchool(school);
        school.persist();
```

Student.java

```
package org.bixin.dugsi.domain;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PostPersist;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.BatchFetch;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.BatchFetchType;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.JoinFetch;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.JoinFetchType;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.activerecord.RooJpaActiveRecord;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class Student extends Person {

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "studentId")
    private String studentIdentifier;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Registration> registrations = new HashSet<Registration>();

    @PostPersist
    public void generateCode() {
        studentIdentifier = ("S-000-");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from these lines:

> 2012-06-26 20:47:29,802 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Student': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager org.bixin.dugsi.domain.Person.entityManager

It seems that you are doing some injection on the entity classes. Need to see the full source for the entities to be sure though. Nevertheless, if you do that.. well.. don't :) Creating spring proxies or doing DI on *every* entity is an overkill, also will almost surely defeat the whole lazy initialization, because Spring will access the ManyToOne collections while doing DI, triggering db load for those entities as well.

*As a sidenote: your entities shouldn't contain business logic, thus there's no reason to do any dependency injection to them.*

Comment: The test that runs this code has just been added, in the test the object is actually a Student object which extends Person and that is the reason this part is being injected. I am not actually controlling which entities are injected at least not directly.

Comment: I can think of 3 reasons why there is DI on your entities: some annotation on the entity class, spring config issue or aspects defined on the project. Can you provide the full Student.java source?

Comment: updated to show student.java, i added the @Joinfetch annotation to my Address.java entity on the OneToMany notation for 'persons' field and it did not hang, it however ran 4 unexpected queries including a select to registrations

Comment: wohooo. `@RooJpaActiveRecord` . That's the one that does the injection. I don't use Roo at all. That said it's a cool thing, but I still argue that putting any logic into the entities makes sense at all.

Comment: **Roo**'s to blame? (Sorry, couldn't help it :D). But seriously, try to remove all of those annotations and see if your getters still get triggered... If so, try to run your query completely stand-alone(write a simple main method, get the `EntityManagerFactory` from a [Persistence](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html) object and run the named query).

Comment: mhmm, removing this will force to me put all getters, setters, finders , toString()/equals() methods.... and manage all of those. Do you have any comments on the use of JoinFetch which ended up referencing all the classes with the three queries in my case (performance wise)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly :) no blame on roo though. if you want just getters/setter/equals/tostring: go lombok! :) http://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html

Comment: So there really is no workaround with roo to stop unnecessary injection of class references, what about push in refactor to get rid of all .aj files generated with roo?

Comment: i just took a deeper look into roo... not as bad as it might seem. The injected fields are static, so the injection 'penalty' would be only on the first creation of your entity types. Try modifying your test case and load all kind of entities in the testcase start. Only try logging/benchmarking after that.

Comment: I have been playing around with JoinFetch since and i added the joinfetch annotation to the address entity which now only runs two select statements the original one i asked for and a reference to the address of only the person i asked for which isnt too bad as i might use it later and it will be cached.

Answer (score 0):

With the fetch set to LAZY access to the Person should not trigger queries to the address or school.  Do you have weaving enabled (using agent or Java EE/Spring weaving)?  You may need to enable dynamic weaving or use static weaving.

It may be something else is triggering the relationships, you could put a breakpoint, or dump the stack trace (using a SessionEvent) in the EclipseLink Session query execution.

Your batch fetch on the address does not make sense, batch fetching is for when the query returns many results, but you are finding by id.  You could use a join fetch (in the JPQL or through the join fetch hint).

I'm not sure how this could hang, break the process to get the stack trace to see what it is waiting on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was confused about the difference and usage scenarios between join fetch and batch fetch which perform much better than writing a standard JPQL. As far as weaving goes, i am using AspectJ (Spring roo) which i believe enables weaving automatically. How can i change it so its set to static/dynamic. I did end up adding as i mentioned in my other post the JoinFetch annotation to the 'persons' field (Address.java) which clears the hanging and only produces two SQL statements. When should you use join fetch and should you use it on the query or as annotation