# eclipselink hangs on bind

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

My EclipseLink JPA (Version 2.6.4) keeps hanging on bind every once in a while on a straight forward select * from entity call.

The OS is an Ubuntu Linux running a mySQL database. The OS, JPA and mySQL version has changed a few times over the last 3 years but the error still happens more often than not. The software currently runs in a Tomcat container.

Here is an excerpt from the code:

```
String sql="SELECT e FROM " + entityName +" e";
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,sql+"["+this.getPuName()+"]");
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
Query query = em.createQuery(sql,this.getEntityType());
query.setMaxResults(maxResults);
result = query.getResultList();
```

In the log this leads to:

```
INFORMATION: SELECT e FROM Person e[com.bitplan.smartcrmRest]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-08-28 09:57:55.472--ServerSession(509447780)--Connection(1675227444)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8090-exec-29,5,main])--SELECT PersonNummer AS a1, EMailStatus AS a2, OEGruppe AS a3, PLZPrivat AS a4, AdressStatus AS a5, akademischerTitel AS a6, aktuelleAuswahl AS a7, Anrede AS a8, Art AS a9, card AS a10, createdAt AS a11, DatenHerkunft AS a12, deletedAt AS a13, email AS a14, EntscheidungsFunktion AS a15, ErstelltVon AS a16, FaxPrivat AS a17, Geburtstag AS a18, Gruppe AS a19, Kommentar AS a20, lastModified AS a21, mailinglists AS a22, Mobiltelefon AS a23, Name AS a24, OrganisationsEinheit AS a25, OrtPrivat AS a26, otheremail AS a27, perDu AS a28, photo AS a29, PositionGruppe AS a30, Rolle AS a31, Sachbearbeiter AS a32, salesEstimate AS a33, salesRank AS a34, sex AS a35, socialLinks AS a36, Sprache AS a37, StrassePrivat AS a38, subid AS a39, TelPrivat AS a40, Telefax AS a41, Telefon AS a42, Titel AS a43, Verhaeltnis AS a44, Vorname AS a45, Wichtigkeit AS a46, MEINEORGANISATION_OrganisationNummer AS a47 FROM Person LIMIT ?, ?
    bind => [0, 100000]
```

and then nothing happens. The behavior seems to depends on the amount of records being returned. We see this hang at some 50.000 records up regularly but it also happens with as few as 200 records. The hang is independent of the table being queried.

I have filed a bug report at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521453

Others have experiences similar issues see e.g.

- [EclipseLink lazy loading hangs on reference class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218379/eclipselink-lazy-loading-hangs-on-reference-class)

This topic has been discussed earlier at

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297266/eclipselink-jpa-hangs-on-bind

and got some interest by the community.

Due to a mistake of mine there was a misunderstanding and the question has been deleted (see quite lively discussion at [My question got deleted by a moderator; how can I find out the reason?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354938/my-question-got-deleted-by-a-moderator-how-can-i-find-out-the-reason)).

This is a restart with the intention to also provide 
a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

**So my question would be - what is a good way to make this reproducible?**

My first thought would be to provide a Docker container using JPA, mySQL and some dummy data and try to get the same issue. What else might be a good approach?

Addendum 2017-12-10: As a hint the following thread dump information might help.

Searching for the mentioned ConcurrencyManager I found e.g.

- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/524575/

**Thread dump**

```
"http-bio-8090-exec-22" #46 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1fdc070800 nid=0x1287 waiting on condition [0x00007f1fe7dfa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConcurrencyManager.releaseDeferredLock(ConcurrencyManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.CacheKey.releaseDeferredLock(CacheKey.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:1069)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:897)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1174)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1133)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1802)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1784)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1749)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)
    at com.bitplan.storage.sql.JPAEntityManager.findAll(JPAEntityManager.java:260)
    at com.bitplan.resthelper.ManagerResourceImpl.getAll(ManagerResourceImpl.java:161)

at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConcurrencyManager.acquire(ConcurrencyManager.java:80)
    - locked <0x000000009d300db0> (a org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.HardCacheWeakIdentityMap$ReferenceCacheKey)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.CacheKey.acquire(CacheKey.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.AbstractIdentityMap.acquireLock(AbstractIdentityMap.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.IdentityMapManager.acquireLock(IdentityMapManager.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.IdentityMapAccessor.acquireLock(IdentityMapAccessor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.IdentityMapAccessor.acquireLock(IdentityMapAccessor.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retrieveCacheKey(AbstractSession.java:5157)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1174)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1133)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3212)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1802)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1784)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2328)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.valueFromRowInternal(OneToOneMapping.java:1848)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2178)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1505)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:897)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1174)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1133)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1802)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1784)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1749)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)
    at com.bitplan.storage.sql.JPAEntityManager.findAll(JPAEntityManager.java:260)
    at com.bitplan.resthelper.ManagerResourceImpl.getAll(ManagerResourceImpl.java:161)
```

In the meantime I suspect that

ConcurrencyManager.releaseDeferredLock

is the culprit.

see e.g.

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389227
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=464105
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440085

Comment: You need to know what is happening before you can reproduce the error reliably.  Is it memory related, database related or a driver error?  If it is stuck though, you should be able to get a thread dump from the JVM and 'see' where exactly it is stuck.  Since you are reading in every entity in the DB into memory, there could be any number of things that could go wrong - such as other threads also building those same entities and just causing a bottleneck or slowdown that appears like it is hanging. Don't forget network or DB slowdowns, and to turn on EclipseLink logging.

Comment: PS why do you think it has anything to do with binding? Does not setting the limit help?  This is not reproducible in any other 'default' simple queries in projects I've seen using EclipseLink, so it really is likely being caused by some setting or value you've done that you are overlooking in your description,or your product architecture itself

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389227 has a similar issue and is not closed after 6 years!

Comment: I can create an app that uses java or database locking and get a deadlock, doesn't make it a bug in java or the database. As stated in one of the threads you linked, Locking is there and needed to prevent returning objects that haven't been fully fetched. The two threads you have shown in your thread dump are not a complete thread dump, and do not show a deadlock. It shows the stack from two different threads, one thread not holding any locks and waiting to release a deferred lock - meaning some other threads building the objects it is looking to return.

Comment: - locked <0x000000009d300db0> (a org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.HardCacheWeakIdentityMap$ReferenceCacheKey) - this indicates a java level lock.  Are there any others in other threads that might be waiting for this one?  What other threads are 'stuck' waiting that are in code that could hold cache keys or java locks?  if you want to reproduce this, you will need to look at the stacks involved to see what is being read in at the time and how the object model is being traversed when being built.

Comment: The problem is still annoying daily after so many years.